# Causes for CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE

Tags: opencl

when I change the work group size from `16` to `32` or something bigger I get an  `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` error. `matrix_size` is `64`.

```
  localWorkSize[0] = groupsize;
  localWorkSize[1] = localWorkSize[0];
  globalWorkSize[0] = matrix_size;
  globalWorkSize[1] = globalWorkSize[0];
```

First I checked the documentation for [clEnqueueNDRangeKernel](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html) which states four (five) different causes `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`, but I think non of them apply. Please check my conclusions. (I hope you don't mind my QA style)

---

**Q** `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE if local_work_size is specified and number of work-items specified by global_work_size is not evenly divisable by size of work-group given by local_work_size`

**A** *64 % 32 = 0*

**Q** `or does not match the work-group size specified for kernel using the __attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(X, Y, Z))) qualifier in program source.`

**A** *As I understood the help, I did not use `__attribute__`.*

**Q** `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE if local_work_size is specified and the total number of work-items in the work-group computed as local_work_size[0] *... local_work_size[work_dim - 1] is greater than the value specified by CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE in the table of OpenCL Device Queries for clGetDeviceInfo.`

**A** *I queried `clGetDeviceInfo` and `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` is `512, 512, 64`*

**Q** `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE if local_work_size is NULL and the __attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(X, Y, Z))) qualifier is used to declare the work-group size for kernel in the program source.`

**A** *`local_work_size` is not `NULL`*.

**Q** `CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE if the number of work-items specified in any of local_work_size[0], ... local_work_size[work_dim - 1] is greater than the corresponding values specified by CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES[0], .... CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES[work_dim - 1].`

**A** *32 < 512*

---

I hope, I haven't overlooked something. Please tell me, when you have an idea what could cause the `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` or found a error in my conclusions.

Thanks for taking the time to read all this :)

Comment: This question is old but I just want to thank you for this very clear explanation because is just found the solution to my problem thanks to it!

Comment: @BigBourin. You are very welcome. Please also +1 Quantumboredom for answering, if you haven't done it yet.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` should return a single `size_t` value (for example 512, but I don't know what it'd be on your system). This is the maximum number of work-items in a work-group, not the maximum in each dimension. So in your case you are trying to make a 2D work-group with 32*32 = 1024 work-items, and presumably `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` is less than 1024 on your system.

See the OpenCL 1.1 spec, table 4.3, page 37, the definition of `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`:

> Maximum number of work-items in a work-group executing a kernel using the data parallel execution model.

Comment: Thank you very much. I indeed used the same variable to read CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES and CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE without clearing. As so often, the error is much more mundane...

Comment: For peoples reference, the OpenCL 1.1 spec https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was trying to run my kernel on CPU. I couldn't set work group size more than 128, while `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` was returning 1024.
After a little bit of search to find out where 128 is coming from it turned out `CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` was giving the proper value.